# Unity 3D: Camera Background Color not applying

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

in my 3D Google Cardboard VR mini game, before switching to another scene, I'd like to fade the current scene's background to white for a nice transition effect.

I built a function which changes the color value from yellow to white whithin 2 seconds:

```
within Update ():

if (started) {
  if (startTime >= startDelay) {
    //start
  } else {
    //fade
    thisBrightness = startTime / 2; // runs 2 seconds
    if (thisBrightness > 1) {
      thisBrightness = 1; // just in case
    }
    Camera.main.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp (mainCameraBackground, mainCameraFaded, thisBrightness);
    startTime += Time.deltaTime;
  }
}
```

I logged the float "thisBrightness" and it changes from 0 to 1 as it should. Also, I can see in the **inspector** that the color field in Camera > Background changes, but in my Game Preview, it does NOT - the color stays.

[image]

Anybody has any explanation and solution for this??!
1000 thanks!

Felix

Unity 5.5.0f3 personal
Google Cardboard 1.0

Comment: At least, by now I found the explanation:
On runtime, Google Cardboard SDK adds 2 new cameras (Left + Right) as children of the Main Camera.
Now I have to find a way to change their background color ;)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I just came back to this question and found it's not really answered.
I found out that **main camera** is converted to **separate cameras left + right** by Google VR SDK.

You'll need to handle both separately, see code below for example how I resoved this in the end:

```
public Camera leftCamera;
public Camera rightCamera;

mainCameraBackground = new Color (1, 0.8f, 0); // set to yellow initially
mainCameraFaded = new Color(1f,1f,1f);
mainCameraCurrent = new Color (0f, 0f, 0f);

// main camera is converted to left + right by Google VR SDK.
// this is why we need to handle both separately

leftCamera.clearFlags = CameraClearFlags.SolidColor;
leftCamera.backgroundColor = mainCameraBackground;

rightCamera.clearFlags = CameraClearFlags.SolidColor;
rightCamera.backgroundColor = mainCameraBackground;
```

and then:

```
mainCameraCurrent = Color.Lerp (mainCameraBackground, mainCameraFaded, thisBrightness);
rightCamera.backgroundColor = mainCameraCurrent;
leftCamera.backgroundColor = mainCameraCurrent;
```

Comment: Hi, please post the solution the question if you found one. This is not a solution to your question. You can edit it and expand your answer.

Comment: @Programmer hope this is sufficient

Comment: Yup that's better. Don't post an answer with just a link since the link may disappear anytime making your answer to be useless. +1